# Can I reason with Dr. Mobius?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just finished OWB and I never got the option to let Dr. Mobius live. The only dialogue option to end the conversation was to kill him.

I did everything in Big MT gathered all personalities, helped every brain in the Think Tank, did all the sidequests and discovered every location.

Any one know if I might have missed anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [New Vegas Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Old_World_Blues_%28add-on%29) notes a potential bug with this quest (verified on the PS3 release, although I imagine the same script issue occurs across platforms):

> If certain choices are made in dialogue, it is impossible to reason with Mobius and killing him becomes the only option, even if the correct skill checks are completed.

They suggest attempting the Repair check as a way to un-bug the dialog tree and get the "non-lethal" options back.  If that fails, you'd probably have to reload an earlier save.

Past this quest, there's no real interaction with Mobius, so unless you really want a particular outcome from this quest, I'd probably suggest moving on if fixing it would be painful.  There aren't any achievements, perks, items, etc, you'll miss out on.

Comment: Well, you miss out on a lifetime supply of free Mentats. But whatever.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I had forgotten he'd give you one per day.  Dude's got a pile of them so large...  plus I never do drugs in Fallout games :P

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIFf2E_th0M